# Having Web Api called by only my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a website and web api. What I want is when ever someone call my web api methods, it should deny the request. But My website call the web api then it should process and respond. It's not just CORS but also when my website C# code request from my website the web api should respond. No other domain request should be responded. I am using asp.net MVC 5, same with web api. How can I accomplish the task.also need to know how I can enable my web api to respond to only cors request that are made from my website also how my web api respond to Website's C# request from my website?

Comment: If you really wanted to do no code change then this can be achieved on the server side itself, meaning IIS level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict either Token, IP Address, or both.

For example,

```
public class TokenValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");

        var authorization = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
        if (authorization != null)
        {
            var authToken = authorization.Parameter;
            var token = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authToken));

            if ("Authorized Token" == token)
                return;
        }

        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}

public class IpHostValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var context = actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] 
           as HttpContextBase;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.UserHostAddress;

        if (ipAddress == "Authorized IP Address")
            return;

        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized IP Address")
        };
    }
}
```

### Usage

You can place those filters on each controller or use Global filter.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(HttpFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new TokenValidationAttribute());
        filters.Add(new IpHostValidationAttribute());
    }
}
```

### Client Helper

```
public static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
    var client = new HttpClient(new RetryHandler(new HttpClientHandler()));

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("API URL");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
         new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var bcreds = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Authorized Token Same As Server");
    var base64Creds = Convert.ToBase64String(bcreds);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", 
        "Basic " + base64Creds);

    return client;
}
```

### Client Usage

```
using (var client = GetHttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<T>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

If you want more security, you might want to look into public key and private key method.

Comment: are these are the only three solutions possible to address the issue?

Comment: Using public key and private key is another solution.

Comment: in your code does " var authorization = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;" return query string?

Comment: @Win beautiful.